# Google Map Chart Marker Clusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to add Marker Clustering to my Google Map chart with no success. I have a function which puts markers on the map based on lat/long. My understanding Map chart will not display more than 400 or so markers, which i don't really want anyway but i'd rather have clustering in place. This way my user sees, for example, single marker for Los Angeles and San Francisco, which would be broken down into multiple when zoom in.

I've looked into https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering
but still can't connect dots and implement it into my function

```
function drawMapChart() {
    var array_map = []
    var header_map=[]
    header_map.push('latitude')
    header_map.push('longitude')
    header_map.push('name')

    array_map.push(header_map)

    array_map.push([{v:34.043736},{v:-118.464298},{v:"city A"}])
    array_map.push([{v:34.043003},{v:-118.448385},{v:"city B"}])

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array_map);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType:'Map',
        containerId:'map_chart_div',
        options:{
            mapType: 'normal'
            },
        dataTable:data
    });
    chart.draw();
}
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: where is the issue? where your code breaks? where is new MarkerClusterer()? have you even try to implemente it? give us more so we can help

Comment: I don't think you can use the MarkerClusterer with those maps, it would need to be a Google Maps JavaScript API v3 map.

Comment: @geocodezip it looks like, at least to me. I thought because mapchart (google charts) uses maps api then MarkerClusterer should work, but i couldn't figure it out. So i just rewrote it following the example in the link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was that my implementation was through map chart (google charts), which from my understanding uses google maps api so i thought it should work. However, i couldn't find the way on how to add MarkerClusterer to that and so as a solution i just rebuilt the page using google maps api (following the example in the link) skipping google chart altogether.